# Use Google font in VS Code

Tags: css, fonts

I'm just trying to install a font family from Google to use in VS code. I downloaded the zip file and installed it, but am not sure how to actually integrate it in the CSS file. Can someone please walk me through how I can apply this Google font family?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

1. Go to [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) and once you have found a perfect font, select it, [this menu will show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQx1F.png) and you can copy this part :

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Inserting it in the `<head>` like this :

```
<head>
   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
   family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

and then in the CSS specify the parts of html that will use this font :

```
p{
   font-family: 'Downloaded font', monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
```

This is how you import google font API in your CSS. Then you can simply use that google font by naming it in your CSS file anywhere just like I have named the imported font below.

```
.body{
 font-family: Muli;
      }
```

If you'd hadn't imported the file then you couldn't use it.